# TS React prop as a dynamic key in array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing a prop to a react component to act as dynamic key (property accessor) for the array of objects (passed as the other prop).
Something like this:

```
const MyComp = ({accessor, data}) => (<div>{data.map(val => <p>{val[accessor]}</p>)}</div>)
```

I'm trying to create a type definition for this component, that will check if:

1. `accessor` is a string
2. `value of data[i][accessor] exists and is a string`

```
const data = [{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'baz'}]
...
<MyComp accessor="foo" data={data} /> // that compiles as both conditions are fulfilled
<MyComp accessor="wrong" data={data} /> // ts should give a warning that `accessor` is not assignable
```

I kinda did it for a simple function:

```
const data = [{ foo: "bar" }, { foo: "baz" }];

type Image = Record<string, any>

function getAProp<T extends Image, K extends keyof T>(
  arr: T[],
  key: K
): string[] {
  return arr.map((v) => `${v[key]}, `);
}

getAProp(data, "foo") // returns a nice array of strings
getAProp(data, "wrong") // ts screams: Argument of type '"wrong"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"foo"'
```

But just can't wrap my head around it how to recreate that as a functional component.
Here's a sandbox with the code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-dynamic-property-prop-problem-6vz86

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `key` props is a special prop in React, so I'd willing to bet it has special types. Please use other name for prop

Comment: good thinking, that was supposed to be just an example, i was not testing that on a live code. thanks